# Google Gmail API - Auth

Tags: asp.net, api, gmail, contacts

I already have code which works fine, but for security reason I want to make other way of Auth.

In this case, user writes his username and password, but I want to make like "Allow demo.com to access your information's" click button.

How to change this code:

```
//Provide Login Information
Google.GData.Client.RequestSettings rsLoginInfo = new Google.GData.Client
        .RequestSettings("", txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);
rsLoginInfo.AutoPaging = true;

// Fetch contacts and dislay them in ListBox
Google.Contacts.ContactsRequest cRequest = new ContactsRequest(rsLoginInfo);
Google.GData.Client.Feed<Google.Contacts.Contact> feedContacts = cRequest
        .GetContacts();
foreach (Google.Contacts.Contact gmailAddresses in feedContacts.Entries) {
    Console.WriteLine("\t" + gmailAddresses.Title);
    lstContacts.Items.Add(gmailAddresses.Title);
    foreach (EMail emailId in gmailAddresses.Emails) {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + emailId.Address);
        lstContacts.Items.Add(" " + emailId.Address);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to do 3-Legged OAuth. .NET samples for performing 3-Legged OAuth 1.0a are documented here:

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html#Examples